# Finding the Range and the Domain of $f(x)=\frac {x^2}{1-x}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Find the domain and range of the function $$f(x)=\frac {x^2}{1-x}$$

---

**My Attempt:** It's obvious to see, from $f(x)$ that $x\neq 1$ or else the denominator equals $0$. So the domain is $$(-\infty,1)\cup (1,+\infty)$$

But for the range, I'm not quite sure. Solving for $y$ in terms of $x$ gives: $$y\cdot (1-x)=x^2\\y-xy-x^2=0\\x^2+xy-y=0$$
After this, I'm not sure what to do. This polynomial isn't factorable!

Comment: Hint: the equation has real roots when $y^2+4y\ge0$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Hm... But how is that going to help the range? I just need the possible $y$-values!

Comment: You should know, as you initiated this path yourself.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Oh wait, I see! The Discriminant is the only part that matters, so therefore, just set the Discriminant larger than of equal to $0$!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the range by studying the function, which we rewrite $f(x)=-(x+1)+1/(1-x)$ for convenience.

Then $f'(x)=-1+1/(1-x)^2$, which cancels at $x=0$, a minimum such that $f(0)=0$ and $x=2$, a maximum such that $f(2)=-4$. Hence the domain $(-\infty,-4]\cup[0,\infty)$.